# How to add a form that is existing to a vb6 project?

Tags: vb6

I have a form "Search.frm" in my vb6 project. I want to add the same form with a different name "SearchNew.frm". I copied the form "Search.frm" and renamed to "SearchNew.frm" and tried to add to the project. But it is giving me an error "Search.frm will not be loaded. Name is already in use".
Can anybody please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the excellent answers and comments above:

- Renaming the file is not enough, VB6 keeps the forms apart by their Name property.
- Temporarily change the Name property of the existing Search.frm
- Add the SearchNew.frm
- Change the Name property of this form
- Change the Name property of the original Search.frm back to what it was.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to add the form.

Answer (score 2):

How to clone a form in VB6:

- Double-click your .frm file in explorer (so your form loads in separate project)
- Change form's (name) in Properties window
- Right-click on form -> Save Search.frm As...

If you are using custom controls thing get trickier:

- Start VB6 and choose blank Standard EXE
- Add Components (Ctrl+T) as necessary
- Add .frm file to project (Ctrl+D)
- Change form's (name)
- Right-click form -> Save As...

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I wrote any VB6 code, but I'm pretty sure you need to change the Name property of the form, not just the filename, in order to use it as a separate form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am not sure how to change the Name property before adding the form. When I browse out to add the file then it would throw the error in a pop up window. I think I would be able to change any properties once it lets me add the form and then go to the form properties. Thanks.

Comment: There are a few things I can think of to try - you could rename the old form before copying it, then rename it back to the old name after adding the copy, or you could try opening the new .frm file in a regular text editor and change the property directly (may or may not work).